# Why does the postGIS file lose geometry?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, gps, geometry, leica-geo-office

I am loading shapefile data from a GPS into PostGIS via Leica ZenoOffice. This apparently imports fine with it's geometry in the attribute table. However, when I add a postGIS layer in QGIS the file uploads but without any geometry (all the other attributes have imported correctly). Is there something specific that this could be such as something simple like a box I have forgotten to tick or is this likely to be a problem with the GPS data itself?

Comment: Does the new table have a row in the geometry_columns table/view?

Comment: Could you clarify how you were able to verify that the import from shapefile picked up the geometry?

Comment: Does the table have a primary key?

Comment: To clarify, the import from the shapefile picked up the geometry as I am able to view this column in postgrsql. However, when I import this into QGIS the geometry_columns disappears from the attributes within QGIS. I hope this is a little clearer :-)

Comment: The attribute table in QGIS does not display the geometry column.

Comment: The attribute table seems to have confused me as to why the shapefile is not being displayed as looking through I can see now that the geometry is not displayed on my other layers and so this cannot be the issue. However, I still cannot view the data I have imported - it appears in the layers list with all the attributes in its table but it is not visible on the QGIS interface - any other ideas as to why this could be or does it sound like a problem with the source data perhaps?

Comment: @kernow88 As far as I know, each row in your attribute table should represent a geometry object.  A common problem is incorrect CRS.  If you right-click the layer and select `zoom to layer`, do you see your points then?

Comment: Scro, no when I zoom to layer there is nothing there. When I open the data in FME from postgresql it is viewable as a feature, but when I add it to QGIS you cannot view it - the attributes have been imported but I cannot see any lines for my feature

Comment: Update on previous comment - clicking around on what apprears to be a blank QGIS screen, I have hit the line of the layer I have imported with the info cursor and it is in the correct place. So it has been imported, I just can't see it - I have tried playing around with the style in the properties tab but to no avail - any ideas?